# Problem with socket (java server) and (esp32 client)

Tags: java, websocket, iot, esp32

i'm trying make a server socket java and esp32 client socket talk but only works one time, after the first time, not work more. if i reset java application work more one time gain, i test with a java client and works well, Somebody help? I don't find the problem, my code below.
thaks
package socket;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Server {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {

            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(80);
            System.out.println("Server ok on port 80");
            while(true){
            Socket cliente = server.accept();
            System.out.println("Client connected from IP " + cliente.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(cliente.getInputStream());
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(cliente.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            BufferedWriter bfw = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);

            while (true) {
                String str = bfr.readLine();
                if (str != null) {
                    System.err.println("client say: " + str);

                    bfw.write("received");
                    bfw.newLine();
                    bfw.flush();

                    if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("by")) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            bfr.close();
            server.close();
            }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

}

esp32 code

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiMulti.h>

WiFiMulti WiFiMulti;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(10);

    // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
    WiFiMulti.addAP("TP-Link_3757", "@ap401mocelin");

    Serial.println();
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Waiting for WiFi... ");

    while(WiFiMulti.run() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        Serial.print(".");
        delay(500);
    }

    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("WiFi connected");
    Serial.println("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

    delay(500);
}


void loop()
{
//    const uint16_t port = 80;
//    const char * host = "192.168.1.1"; // ip or dns
    const uint16_t port = 80;
    const char * host = "192.168.0.114"; // ip or dns

    Serial.print("Connecting to ");
    Serial.println(host);

    // Use WiFiClient class to create TCP connections
    WiFiClient client;

    if (!client.connect(host, port)) {
        Serial.println("Connection failed.");
        Serial.println("Waiting 5 seconds before retrying...");
        delay(5000);
        return;
    }

    // This will send a request to the server
    //uncomment this line to send an arbitrary string to the server
    //client.print("Send this data to the server");
    //uncomment this line to send a basic document request to the server
    client.print("GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\n\n");

  int maxloops = 0;

  //wait for the server's reply to become available
  while (!client.available() && maxloops < 1000)
  {
    maxloops++;
    delay(1); //delay 1 msec
  }
  if (client.available() > 0)
  {
    //read back one line from the server
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
    Serial.println(line);
    client.flush();
    client.stop();
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("client.available() timed out ");
  }

    Serial.println("Closing connection.");
    client.flush();
    client.stop();

    Serial.println("Waiting 5 seconds before restarting...");
    delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: send "by" to jump out of the while loop in java. until then the server can't accept a new connection

Comment: move ```server.close();``` out of the loop and switch to "thread-per-client" model (i.e. run inner loop in a extra thread)